# why is my python if statement is not working

Tags: python, if-statement

so im pretty sure everything is correct but here it is not working, I would really apperciate it if someone could help me, this code is meant to make you choose between 3 doors, and after you choose a door, it will tell you a door that it is not it also that is not the door that you choose, finally this last part is meant to print the code

```
import random
import time

prize = (random.randint(1,3))
randomDoor = 7
question = 0



door = input ("Choose a door: 1, 2, ou 3")

print ("you chose door...", door)


#########               PRIZE IS 1                  ################################
if (prize == 1 and door == 1):
        print("random door = 3")
        randomDoor = 3

if (prize == 1 and door == 2):
        randomDoor = 3
        
if (prize == 1 and door == 3):
        randomDoor = 2
        

#################               PRIZE IS 2             #############################
if (prize == 2 and door == 1):
        randomDoor = 3

if (prize == 2 and door == 2):
        randomDoor = 3

if (prize == 2 and door == 3):
        randomDoor = 1
        
####################        PRIZE IS 3              ##############################
if (prize == 3 and door == 1):
        randomDoor = 2
        
if (prize == 3 and door == 2):
        randomDoor = 1

if (prize == 3 and door == 3):
        randomDoor = 1




print (randomDoor, "has nothing in it")
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"?

Comment: The issue is `door` is a string, so the comparisons to int won't work.  Try converting door to int with: `door = int(input ("Choose a door: 1, 2, ou 3"))`

Comment: `door` is a string.  It will not match ANY of your `if` statements, do `randomDoor` will remain at 7.  You need `door = int(input(...))`.

Comment: And, by the way, Python `if` statements do not use those extra parentheses.  That is a bad habit left over from C coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random


prize = (random.randint(1,3))
randomDoor = 7
question = 0



door = int(input ("Choose a door: 1, 2, ou 3"))

print ("you chose door...", door)


#########               PRIZE IS 1                  ################################
if (prize == 1 and door == 1):
        print("random door = 3")
        randomDoor = 3

if (prize == 1 and door == 2):
        randomDoor = 3
        
if (prize == 1 and door == 3):
        randomDoor = 2
        

#################               PRIZE IS 2             #############################
if (prize == 2 and door == 1):
        randomDoor = 3

if (prize == 2 and door == 2):
        randomDoor = 3

if (prize == 2 and door == 3):
        randomDoor = 1
        
####################        PRIZE IS 3              ##############################
if (prize == 3 and door == 1):
        randomDoor = 2
        
if (prize == 3 and door == 2):
        randomDoor = 1

if (prize == 3 and door == 3):
        randomDoor = 1




print (randomDoor, "has nothing in it")
```

changes :

```
door = int(input ("Choose a door: 1, 2, ou 3"))
```

When you get an input, if you do not specify its type, it is a string by default